# PhpStorm: Cannot find type but actually can?

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

PhpStorm shows me errors like this pretty frequently:

[image]

It says

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'StringNum'.

But then below:

> Alias for: string|number

Which is correct. It even shows where it found the definition.

I'm guessing the former error is coming from the TS Language Server, and the latter is from PhpStorm's magic heuristics.

It's super confusing though -- how can I synchronize them so that it's either an error or not, none of this half-and-half?

---

Here's another one

[image]

Comes from using a `const` called `Sentry` which I've declared in `sentry.d.ts` as

```
declare const Sentry: typeof import('@sentry/browser')|undefined
```

I don't `import` or `/// reference` this file anywhere, I was hoping the `"include"` in my `tsconfig.json` would pick those up:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "include": [
        "./scripts/types/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What code produces this error? The first error is indeed coming from Typescript, which I would trust more than the second message. Perhaps the second message is an import suggestion, and once imported it will solve the type error? It's hard to advise without the code creating these messages.

Comment: I can share code, but the point isn't to get TS to resolve this particular error, it's to get PhpStorm to behave in a consistent manor. These should either be found or not found. It's an import suggestion, those look different.

Comment: Most probably the file TSC errors are reported in is not included in `tsconfig.json` that includes the typings. Normally the nearest `tsconfig.*.json` current file is included in is used for errors reporting.

Comment: @lena Is there a way to tell which tsconfig file PhpStorm is looking at? I have other errors here that aren't consistent with what I've set is my tsconfig.json, but I don't see any other tsconfig files.

Comment: if this is the only `tsconfig.*` file in your project, please make sure that your files are included in it (check `"files": []`, `"include":[]`, `"exclude":[]` fields)